# How add two path variables whose path has spaces using batch script

Tags: batch-file, variables, path

```
SET A="C:\Users\MyUser\Documents"
SET B="\Project\User Notes & Samples\MyAppnotes\commands.bat"
```

add `A` and `B` to and store in `Result` path

```
Result = "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Project\User Notes & Samples\MyAppnotes\commands.bat"
```

Comment: why do you set some paths with no spaces before and after the `=` and the others you don't? Why do you not use the `set` command in the result line?

Comment: Your question is rather lacking in detail, for example how result is to be used would be very helpful for selecting the most appropriate method.

Comment: I mean i have two variables which store the paths where in the path have spaces and special characters , i need the combined path in another variable.

Comment: To simplify i need to combine two paths(which has spaces and special characters) in two variables and i need them to be concatenated into one variable

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and clarify, currently as it is, it is unclear and it will be closed. Show expected results as well.

Answer (score 0):

The non recommended `set` syntax you've used, is probably the source of your issue, because the doublequotes are included in your variable values. In order to remove them you'd need to expand those variables removing both their first and last characters:

```batch-file
@Set A="C:\Users\MyUser\Documents"
@Set B="\Project\User Notes & Samples\MyAppnotes\commands.bat"
@Echo Result = "%A:~1,-1%%B:~1,-1%"
@Pause
```

If however, you used the recommended syntax when setting your variables, `Set "VariableName=Variable Value"`. This type of syntax protects the content spaces but does not include the doublequotes in the variable name or value. Then you can safely concatenate the two variables, adding any required doublequotes as necessary..

```batch-file
@Set "A=C:\Users\MyUser\Documents"
@Set "B=\Project\User Notes & Samples\MyAppnotes\commands.bat"
@Echo Result = "%A%%B%"
@Pause
```